# Varnish trailing slash rewrite

Tags: varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I'm trying to setup varnish to handle my default url which is example.url.co.uk.

If it hits example.url.co.uk or example.url.co.uk/ I want it to redirect or rewrite to example.url.co.uk/site which within the tomcat application sends it to a login page.

```
sub vcl_recv {

if ((req.url ~ "") || (req.url ~"^/")) {
       set req.http.location = "https://example.url.co.uk/site" + req.url;
       return (synth(750, "Found"));
     }

}


sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 301) {
        set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
        return (deliver);
    }

    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.http.Location = req.http.location;
        set resp.status = 302;
        return (deliver);
    }

}
```

However when I use my attempt that this I get example.url.co.uk/site/site/site/site...

So I'm obviously stuck in a loop and I've been banging my head on this for a week trying to find the right solution! Please save me from my own stupidity I'm sure!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `req.url ~ ""`  matches everthing. as it is used as a regular expression.  also your `req.url ~ "^/"`  is too open.

changing it to:

`if (req.url == "" || req.url ~"^/$") {`

should fix it, verifying that it is either empty or `/`  it self.

here is a simple varnishtest to verify the behaviour:

```
varnishtest "Test Redirect"

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp
    rxreq
    txresp
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend { 


sub vcl_recv {

if (req.url == "" || req.url ~"^/$") {
       set req.http.location = "https://example.url.co.uk/site" + req.url;
       return (synth(750, "Found"));
     }

}


sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 301) {
        set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
        return (deliver);
    }

    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.http.Location = req.http.location;
        set resp.status = 302;
        return (deliver);
    }

}


} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/" 
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 302
} -run


client c1 {
    txreq -url "/site" 
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
} -run
```

you can run it with `varnishtest test.vtc`